# Disable Tab Bar storyboard appearance setting programmatically

Tags: swift, uitabbar, ios13, ios12

My app is required to be iOS 12.0 compatible and has a tab bar. Since iOS 13.0, the `UITabBarAppearance()` can be used to change its appearance. In the storyboard, I have `Standard` selected as `Appearances` within the attributes inspector. This makes the app crash when iOS 12.0 is used.

How can I disable standard appearance programmatically?

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    // code for iOS >= 13.0
} else {
    // code for iOS < 13.0
    // Here I would like to disable the storyboard standard appearances
}
```

Comment: You cannot load the storyboard at all. Code can't undo that.

Comment: It's not about loading the storyboard. It's changing/overriding programmatically a selection made on storyboard.

Comment: It _is_ about loading the storyboard. You are _crashing_ because the storyboard is incompatible with the system. You said it yourself: "In the storyboard, I have Standard selected as Appearances within the attributes inspector. This makes the app crash when iOS 12.0 is used."

Comment: I suggest that your create your own tab bar if you have to support older OS version. Less headache as it is easier to maintain and support newer version of OS

Comment: @matt Understood. I assumed that I could configure storyboard and change _any_ configuration done later on programmatically. Apparently wrong. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AchmadJP Didn't know that it was possible to change the Tab Bar (Controller?) iOS version in a single project, and have 2 Tab Bars in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured the storyboard to use a class (UITabBarAppearance) that doesn't exist in iOS 12. So if the app runs on iOS 12, when storyboard loads: Kaboom.

If you want this app to be backward compatible, do things the other way: configure the tab bar the *old* way in the storyboard and then switch to the *new* way in your (conditional) code.

Comment: Done that way now. Works! Thanks,